# antlr4 expression separator with '\n' and let parser to ignore '\n' like in Kotlin

Tags: parsing, newline, antlr4, lexer

I make grammar with antlr4 and encountered a problem with expression separation
I need to be able to separate expressions with the next line like in Kotlin, Swift or JavaScript
For example:

```
a = 5
b = 10
c = a + b
```

Here, each line is new expression, which is separated from the others by a next line character '\n'
But i also wants, that '\n' don't separate not-full expression like that

```
a =
10 + 15
```

where `a = 10 + 15` is whole expression
How can i make it?

i surfed internet, but didn't find even crutch solutions (((
i thought replacing

```
Int : [0-9]+;
WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip;
```

with something like this

```
Int : [0-9]+ WS;
WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+;
```

will helps, but i just got a lot of errors of parsing